# What is 0.54 to be rounded to 0.55 as called as?

Tags: phrases

In MS excel we call

1. `2.5`  to be rounded to `3` as **rounding up to the Nearest Whole Number**
2. `11.45`/`11.75` to be rounded to `11.5`/`11.8` as **rounding up to Nearest 10th**

What is

1. `0.23` to be  rounded to `0.25` (instead of 0.3) as rounding up to the ??? called
2. `0.54`  to be rounded to `0.55` as rounding up to the ??? called
3. `1.61` to be  rounded to `1.65` as rounding up to the ??? called

Where the digits after decimal is always in form of 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65 or 0.75 and so on

Background:
I am trying to find online tutorial to use the MS excel's round up, round down, mround, ceiling, floor function but I cannot find desired search results unless I put the right question.(usually the above functions return rounded numbers (0.30 or 1.70, etc) or sometimes random 0.x5 numbers without any consistency)

Comment: Under what rounding scheme would 0.23 become 0.25 or 1.61 become 1.65?

Comment: @KillingTime I got a website providing the solution. says How to Round Numbers in Excel Using 3 Rounding Functions    https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/how-to-round-numbers-in-excel-using-round-formulas

Comment: Does "called as" just mean "called"? What about "as called as"?

Comment: Try *quantization increment* or *quantization step size*.  But getting a quant of 0.1 to round to 0.05, 0.15, 0.25 is not something I've seen.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)) is better than I though it would be.

Comment: Found it. *Mid tread quantization* yields 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, etc. *Mid riser quantization* yields 0.05, 0.15, 0.25, etc. quantization.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're looking for "rounding up to the nearest 0.05" ([usage example](https://magoosh.com/gre/gre-math-rounding/) for "rounding to the nearest 0.05"; "rounding up" is analagous to "rounding"). Alternative phrases could be "rounding to the nearest multiple of 0.05", or "rounding to the nearest twentieth".

Commonly, rounding is assumed to be to the nearest whole number ("to the nearest 1"). You can also round to the nearest 2 (to the nearest even number), to the nearest 0.1 (to the nearest tenth, as you give in your answer), etc..

Comment: And if you’re a machinist it’s to the nearest fifty thousandths.

Answer (score -2):

> I am trying to find online tutorial to use the MS excel's round up, round down, mround, ceiling, floor function

These are all "rounding functions"

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y97eyKkqLhg

Comment: Excel tutorials are not on-topic here; and the question asked for a particular type of rounding function.